# Rewrite URL with .htaccess does not direct to the new URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use .htaccess to rewrite the URL

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^book/([^/]*)$ /book.php?book=$1 [NC,L]
```

This works great, and if I type `http://www.domain.org/book/title1` in a browser's address bar it takes me there. But when I click the link on the index page it takes me to the old address `http://www.domain.org/book.php?book=title1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you don't have any rules that does the redirect. Have it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+book\.php\?book=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /book/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^book/([^/]+)/?$ book.php?book=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```